# Problema con chartjs usando react

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, chart.js

Hola tengo un problema y resulta que necesito insertar una grafica a mi proyecto realizo la respectiva instalación del modulo con el siguiente comando: npm install --save react-chartjs-2 chart.js y realizo la respectiva configuración para mostrar la grafica pero al momento de iniciar mi proyecto arroja este error.

```
`./node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.esm.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6881:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         if (intermediateIndex1 !== startIndex && intermediateIndex1 !== lastIndex) {
|           decimated.push({
|             ...data[intermediateIndex1],
|             x: avgX,
|           });`
```

Aquí dejo mi código, en el cual realizo una grafica de linea, el cual no tiene mayor ciencia solo que no comprendo porque me arroja ese error ya que pareciera que fue problema del modulo o de la instalación del mismo.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

<Line
height={400}
width={600}
data={{
labels: [
'January',
'February',
'March',
'April',
'May',
'June',
'July',
'August',
'September',
'October',
'November',
'December'
],
datasets: [
{
label: 'Active Users',
borderColor: '#f96332',
fill: false,
backgroundColor: [ 'red' ],
data: [ 542, 480, 430, 550, 530, 453, 380, 434, 568, 610, 700, 630 ]
}
]
}}
options={{
plugins: {
legend: {
display: false
}
},
responsive: true,
scales: {
x: {
display: false
}
}
}}
/>
```

y aquí les dejo mi archivo en json para que revisen que el modulo de chartjs se encuentra instalado.

```
  {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "datatables.net-bs5": "^1.11.2",
    "mdbreact": "^5.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.0",
    "react-chartjs": "^1.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^3.3.0",
    "react-data-table-component": "^7.0.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-html-table-to-excel": "^2.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.1.5",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

Me seria de gran ayuda su colaboración ya que no se que más intentar y segun lo que he visto en diferentes sitios de está forma deberia funcionar sin problema, les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Al parecer, chartjs 3 no es compatible. Utiliza la versión 2.9.4. Checa esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67081096/chart-js-error-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type

Comment: amigo no se si me funciono debido a que instale esa versión y ahora me arroja esto:      ./node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist/index.modern.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'chart.js/auto' in '/home/juan/Desktop/newnet/client/node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist'